# Finding the right model

Tags: r, svm

I have a data frame with several predictors, lets call them `pred1` through `pred3`, and a result column. Now I need to specify the right model. I could randomly try:

```
svm.model <- svm(result ~ pred1+pred2+pred3,       data = train)
# or
svm.model <- svm(result ~ pred1*pred2+pred3^2,     data = train)
# or
svm.model <- svm(result ~ log2(pred1)+pred2*pred3, data = train)
# etc. etc.
```

But there must be a better automatic approach in R to model selection?!

Comment: Thanks alot! But assuming that I don't know anything yet about the background? I found the penalizedSVM package but it seems its only for classification and not regression.

Comment: For this question in particular, you should look methods for "feature selection" as there are automated ways that attempt to select the best set of a variables for a model. After that you should also look into tuning your model to select the best parameters. Both of these are made relatively easy with R's `caret` package: http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/featureselection.html.

Comment: The thing is, that want to combine features in a non linear way, like multiplying each other. And trying everything from hand is pretty annoying, but I could improve the model alot by that.

Comment: Automated approches such as Stepwise Regression and LASSO can be very dangerous and lead to misleading results. Use Bayesian methods for variable selection, which incorporates model uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

For unknown nonlinear dependences, there are nonlinear models. The most commonly used are tree models, i. e. random forest (package randomForest) and boosted trees (package gbm) and neural networks.

If you want to use linear regression for nonlinear dependence, one possibility is to create a big polynom with lots of terms, and then do stepwise elimination.  Use logarithms if (and only if) the feature change orders of magnitude, i.e. you try to predict the life span of arbitrary animal from its weight.

Another possibility is to try Kernel Ridge Regression.

You may also want to read about Generalized Additive Model.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very cautious in applying these "random" methods. Any model has to have a strong background in discipline-specific theory.

If you do find a satisfactory model using the algorithms suggested, you're still left with the formidable task of justifying why it theoretically makes sense. "The stats model says that pred1 and pred3 predict the result" is not an acceptable answer.

With a different run of the pred1, pred2, pred3, the relationship you thought you built may prove no longer hold. In that case, the whole exercise becomes invalid.

Comment: I suppose it's to some extent a philosophical question, but it's not necessarily the case that _any model has to have a strong background in discipline-specific theory._ Models that are theory-driven are useful in some instances, but one could cite "theory-dependence" as a disadvantage. At the other extreme, there are data-driven models and these, too, have their uses, however, "sample-dependence" may be cited as a disadvantage in this case. Perhaps one should find a middle-ground to reduce both theory and sample dependence? Arguably, discipline-specific theory is not necessary nor sufficient.

Comment: I'm not claiming a model should be solely theory-driven. The problem is that you can't get around explaining why the results work. A working model stands up to the scrutiny of replication, and you can't achieve that by saying that perd1 and pred3 predict the results. They predict the results with the *current* data you put in. If somebody else comes along and tries to replicate this with another run of pred1 and pred3, it's entirely possible they may get no significant results at all.

Comment: The question then follows (for the OP): what is the purpose of the model? If the model is to be used to _explain_ then obviously some theoretical foundation would be desirable, e.g. when building a structural model in economics. On the other hand, if the model's purpose is to solely _produce forecasts_ then the results don't necessarily require any explanation and the need for theory is reduced - or, indeed, eliminated altogether. e.g. when, say, bulk forecasting inventory stock. Whether or not the forecasts are optimal with or without theory is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me whether or not this is an R programming question or a statistics question. In any case, I'll address the issue of trying to come up with a better automatic approach in R (in order to save the OP from the annoyance of typing!). My answer may not be pretty, but let me throw the idea out there anyway!

In terms of exhausting a list of potential models, you could try creating a big loop like this:

```
signs <- c("+","*")
trans <- c("","^2","^3")
for(i in signs){
  for(j in signs){
    for(k in trans){
      for(l in trans){
        for(m in trans){
          print(paste(paste("svm(result ~ pred1",k,sep=""),i,paste("pred2",l,sep=""),j,paste("pred3",m, sep=""),paste(", data=train)")))
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

This loop will save you the effort of having to randomly try different models; the loop will, instead, systematically go through a complete list of models. Play around with the `signs` and `trans` vectors to add more combinations of models to the list.

Note: You'll have to tweak the loop to estimate the models rather than have the loop simply print out strings of text - I've set up the loop this way for the purpose of illustration.

A warning: using this method to find a model is more or less a pure data mine! I'll leave it to you decide whether or not this is a good or bad strategy!

---

Below is a snapshot of output that the loop produces:

```
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2^2 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2^2 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2^2 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2^3 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2^3 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2^3 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2^2 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2^2 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2^2 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2^3 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2^3 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^2 + pred2^3 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2^2 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2^2 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2^2 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2^3 + pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2^3 + pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 + pred2^3 + pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2 * pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2 * pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2 * pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2^2 * pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1 + pred2^2 * pred3^2 , data=train)"
# --- Lots More Output here ---
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 * pred2^2 * pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 * pred2^2 * pred3^3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 * pred2^3 * pred3 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 * pred2^3 * pred3^2 , data=train)"
[1] "svm(result ~ pred1^3 * pred2^3 * pred3^3 , data=train)"
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest not to use this approach, especially because specific functions for variable selection exist, such as the `stepAIC` function in the MASS package. See [the Quick-R page on multiple regression](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html) for examples.

Comment: That's really helpful @nico. The leaps package also looks quite good too.